# Вопрос о внедрении зависимостей

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

Всем привет!

У меня есть несколько вопросов по механизму внедрения зависимостей в Java. Чтобы было понятнее постараюсь проиллюстрировать вопросы.

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что при использовании `@Inject` к полю класса, механизм внедрения зависимостей создаст новый экземпляр компонента?

Допустим в каком-то классе я в первый раз использую `@Inject`.

```
    @Inject
    private JWTAuthContextInfo authContextInfo;
```

Будет ли это равносильно тому, что я вызову new?

```
    private JWTAuthContextInfo authContextInfo = new JWTAuthContextInfo();
```

2. Если я применю `@Inject` еще раз (в другом классе), то что я получу? Будет создан еще один экземпляр или механизм DI подставит предыдущий экземпляр компонента?

В другом классе я снова применяю `@Inject`

```
    @Inject
    private JWTAuthContextInfo authContextInfo;
```

Вызовет ли CDI `new`?

```
    private JWTAuthContextInfo authContextInfo = new JWTAuthContextInfo();
```

Или он подставит предыдущий созданный компонент?

Буду благодарен всем за ответы!

Comment: Почитайте про время жизни компонентов. Если я верно помню, они по умолчанию синглтоны (один экземпляр на всё), но это можно переопределять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь все зависит от того как вы пропишете ваши зависимости. Если у к примеру вы в модуле напишете метод

```
@Provides
@Singleton
static JWTAuthContextInfo provide JWTAuthContextInfo() {
    return new JWTAuthContextInfo();
}
```

То вы создадите ваш объект один раз, после чего Dagger его закеширует и будет отдавать этот же экземпляр всякий раз когда вы его попросите.

```
@Provides
static JWTAuthContextInfo provide JWTAuthContextInfo() {
    return new JWTAuthContextInfo();
}
```

В этом случае Dagger будет будет всегда создавать новый объект.

Вы так же можете описать [свою аннотацию Scope](https://habr.com/ru/post/279641/) и с помощью нее определять сколько будет жить ваш объект.

И вообще рекомендую к прочтению [серию статей по Dagger 2](https://habr.com/ru/post/279125/).

Comment: Сергей, подскажите, пожалуйста, это справедливо только для Dagger или работает в любой реализации CDI (мы используем Weld)? И по умолчанию для компонентов выбирается синглтон подход?

Comment: Вот ту я вам не подскажу.

Comment: Все равно спасибо)